# input type bug with decimal validation

Tags: html, validation

I'm working in a solution with HTML5.

I'm try implement validation using input type numeric.

I'm get a error in the validation on client side.

in this input:

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" step="1" min="120.50" max="2410.00" value="0">
```

I get a error message **"The nearest valid value is 2409.5"**

Why I get this error if the max is 2410.00?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The min end on 0.50 and advance one on one then max is 2409.50.
You have to put step="0.50"